# Mod_rewrite trouble (easy?)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to work on a PHP website using Zend Studio.
There are a ton of mod_rewrite rules in the .htaccess file.
One of these rules is the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /fitch/index.php?cmd=homepage [NC,L,QSA]
```

I want to run this website on my local Apache-Zend server.
I tried to create an additional rule below that one like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /fitch/index.php?cmd=homepage [NC,L,QSA]
```

I want to make it such that if the server is given the url `http://localhost/index.php` it redirects to `http://localhost/fitch/index.php?cmd=homepage`

But there seems to be some error because I cannot restart Apache with that in place.
If anyone could help me out I would appreciate it!

Comment: That just creates a redirect loop, what you have added.  Converting `localhost` to `localhost` - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The first rule is to ensure that the site is only accessed via **www.mysite.com** not just **mysite.com**.

Comment: Edited to answer your question

Comment: Just need the last rule on it's own for that.  It will redirect `http://localhost/` to `http://localhost/fitch/index.php?cmd=homepage`.  `^/?$` means the path (after the domain) should match nothing or just a slash, and change to the path afterwards.

Comment: You mean the whole last line? How about to rewrite http://localhost/login.php to http://localhost/fitch/login.php ?

Comment: Try adding this line: `RewriteRule ^(.+\.php)$ /fitch/$1 [NC,L,QSA]`